# http connections stuck in close_wait state

Tags: go, tcp

I'm using gin to build a simple api server. right now, after the server started a few minutes later, all of incoming requests were stuck. After checking connections state , I got a message like below :[image]

I already have tried to set c.Request.Close=true or c.Header("Connection","close") or both of them, but it was not working. I was wondering if anyone can help me fix this issue.

**UPDATE-1**    the way to start server

```
            runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
            //start serving
            r := gin.New()
            r.Use(gin.LoggerWithWriter(logFile))
            r.Use(gin.RecoveryWithWriter(logFile))
            r.Use(handler.SetResponseHeader())
            controller.Router.RegisterRouter(r, cfg)

            //r.Run(cfg.SvcHost)
            s := &http.Server{
                Addr:    cfg.SvcHost,
                Handler: r,
            }
            s.ListenAndServe()
```

**UPDATE-2**

after temporarily disabling the global gorm.DB instance and creating a new db connection for each request, this issue didn't occur any more.

Comment: Possibly you need to read the response fully on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is waiting for you to close those connections. Probably you have read end of stream from them and have ignored it.

Comment: How could I close the connections properly ? Are you saying the client side didn't close the connection after reading end of the stream ?

Comment: No, I *said* that *you* haven't closed the connection. I don't know how you close a socket in Go, and this is not helped by your failure to post any code.

Comment: sorry, due to my poor english, I possibly misunderstood. I posted some code, which is how I start the server.